# Does the English "Forseek" have any ties to the NHG. "versuchen?" Can the English word be spoken with the same sense as the NHG. one?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

I've stumbled upon the English word *"forseek"*  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forseek. The word itself is from Old English *"forsēcan"* http://old-engli.sh/dictionary.php (though the OE word does not have the same meaning that "forseek" does today). Today it means "to seek out, to seek thoroughly for [something]." 
I was wondering if "forseek" has any links to the NHG. "versuchen" (to try, attempt) since they are both made up of the same word-bits "for- => ver-" and "seek => suchen". Can "forseek" be spoken with the same sense of the NHG. versuchen? "I tried to do it => I *forsought* to do it?"

Comment: 'Forseek' does not appear in AHD, Collins, RHK Webster's, CED, ODO ... I think we can regard it as obsolete, and I'm pretty sure OED would label it as such.

Comment: Though they seem like great cognates, doesn't versuchen mean try? Don't know forseek, but grant you that the prefix-verb shape is very English-from-German: forsake, betroth, besotted.

Comment: You could make an argument based on the parts of the words. *Seek* > OE *sécan* > ... > MHG *sûchen* // *For-* > OE *for-* > ... > MHG and modern German *ver-* (OED) // But just because the stem and affix share roots doesn't mean that the words in completion are related.  Afterall, they do seem to mean different things.

Answer (score 1):

While they certainly come from the same root, which I believe is Indo-European sag -  http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?single=1&basename=%2fdata%2fie%2fpokorny&text_number=1640&root=config - I think their prefixes serve different purposes.

The English is in the sense of thoroughly, whilst the German ver- is in the sense of for, "in order to". https://yourdailygerman.com/2013/11/01/german-prefix-ver-explained/

I would parallel versuchen with the English phrasing "I'm seeking to [understand etc]"